# Kotlin: Store current date in Firestore as timestamp

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Not sure why I can't find what I'm looking for. But I just want to store the current time into a Firestore document like this:

[image]

. In Flutter we just do this:

```
'timestamp': DateTime.now()
```

I tried doing this in kotlin:

```
"timestamp" to LocalDateTime.now()
```

But it gives me some complicated field:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way on all platforms is to use the server timestamp token provided by the SDK (and not using the client's clock, which could be wrong).

The documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).

```
// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
val updates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
        "timestamp" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
)

docRef.update(updates).addOnCompleteListener { }
```

If you really do want the client clock's time, just pass a java Date with `Date()` or [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) with `Timestamp.now()`.